# R言語で、計算結果をtxtかcsvで出力する方法が知りたい

Tags: r

下記の計算結果を、txtかcsvでファイルに出力したく、ご教示いただけませんでしょうか。

```
#CSVファイルを読み込む
a <- read.csv("testfile.csv")

#列Aを表示
print(a$A) # あるいはprint(a[, 'A'])
print(a$B)
print(a$C)


#A列の統計値を求める
#平均
mean(a$A)
#中央値
median(a$A)
#最頻値
names(which.max(table(a$A)))


#B列の統計値を求める
#平均
mean(a$B)
#中央値
median(a$B)
#最頻値
names(which.max(table(a$B)))


#C列の統計値を求める
#平均
mean(a$C)
#中央値
median(a$C)
#最頻値
names(which.max(table(a$C)))



#計算した統計値を結果をデータに保存する
???
```

結果（イメージ。フォーマットは違っても可）

```
 ,平均,中央値,最頻値
A,結果,　結果,　結果
B,結果,　結果,　結果
C,結果,　結果,　結果
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

例えばこんな感じでしょうか。

```
# 最頻値を返す(同率1位の場合の対応はしていない)
my_mode <- function(x) {
  names(which.max(table(x)))
  # as.integer(names(which.max(table(x)))) とすると整数として返します
}
# 同じデータ構造に異なる関数を繰り返し適用する目的で定義しています
methods <- c('mean', 'median', 'my_mode')

a <- read.csv('testfile.csv')   
# forでも書けますがapply系の関数を覚えると便利かと思います
result <- sapply(methods, function(method) {
  sapply(a, function(column) {
    # 動的な関数呼び出しを行うものです。詳しくは?do.callなどで。。
    do.call(method, list(column))
  })
})
# ヘッダを変更します。
colnames(result) <- c('平均', '中央値', '最頻値')
write.csv(result, file='result.csv')
```

以下、余談です。

ご存じかもしれませんが、`R`はわからない関数などの頭に`?`を付けると、ヘルプを表示してくれます。たとえば`sapply`がわからない場合は`?sapply`と`R`のコンソールに尋ねることができます。

`R`の基本文法については[RjpWiki - RjpWiki](http://www.okada.jp.org/RWiki/)などを参考にされても良いかもしれません。英語ということでとっつきにくいかもしれませんが[R for cats · and cat lovers](http://rforcats.net/) (日本で言う「猫でもわかる」系チュートリアル）も個人的には面白くて好きです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
ご紹介いただいたサイト、大変勉強になります。

ヘルプ機能も気がついておりませんでした。大変便利になりました。